# How to find if a network interface is using dhcp/static ip without relying on sh (e.g. `ip route`) using python?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, network-programming, rhel

I currently need to find out if **any** network interface (on RHEL) is configured to use dynamic IP (DHCP) using python (python2 preferably, but if there's a solution using python3, I'd like to hear it).

I **don't want** to throw a bash subprocess and just parse the response from `ip route` or `nmcli` for instance.

What we tried/found out so far:

1. There's a python lib (currently archived) [netifaces](https://github.com/al45tair/netifaces) but even with that we were not able to make it give us that answer. Also having second thoughts of depending on a lib that has been archived a while ago.
2. On `/sys/class/net` it's possible to see the interfaces and on it there are a lot of properties, but none of it seems to give what we want. Maybe there's another Linux interface that could give us that?!
3. On `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-**` it's possible to see options of every interface (NetworkManager is the owner I guess) and one could parse the `BOOTPROTO=` option. However, that does not necessarily show the current connection method because one could change that file or even modify the interface through `nmcli` and that would only be read after the interface has been restarted (down/up)

Note: Sorry if some specific network terms were not correctly used, I'm not an expert there :)

Any thoughts? Any ideas?

Comment: *I don't want to throw a bash subprocess and just parse the response from ip route or nmcli for instance.* Why not?

Comment: You can have a look at [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/routing.html)

Comment: @user56700 I think I'd need more characters I have to debate it, but let's say that this is not a good practise to keep creating subprocess and relying on bash to do production work.

Comment: @0x0fba quickly checked, and it seems to not give me that info directly. Thanks though, seems to be an interesting lib

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with just listing directory/reading config files, I only care about real IP interfaces:

```
import os
import psutil


def get_network_interfaces():
    interfaces = psutil.net_if_addrs()
    return interfaces


def get_interface_types():
    interface_names = os.listdir(r'/etc/network/interfaces.d/')
    inet_types = dict()

    for inet in interface_names:
        # inet: eth0.cfg
        interface_file_path = f'/etc/network/interfaces.d/{inet}'
        with open(interface_file_path, 'r') as file:
            content = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')
            inet_types[inet[:-4]] = 'Static' if 'manual' in content else 'DHCP'

    return inet_types


def print_network_info():
    interfaces = get_network_interfaces()
    interfaces_types = get_interface_types()

    print("Network Interfaces:")
    for interface_name, addresses in interfaces.items():
        print(f"Interface: {interface_name}")

        for address in addresses:
            if str(address.family) == 'AddressFamily.AF_INET':
                print(f"  IP Address: {address.address}")
                print(f"  Type: {interfaces_types.get(interface_name)}")

        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_network_info()
```

[image]